# Vugu (Go) framework: @click event is not working

Tags: go

This is an example as shown in the Vugu docs, yet it doesn't seem to work.
https://www.vugu.org/doc/dom-events

The Toggle function does not get called.

```
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="root">
            <div>
                <div vg-if='c.Show'>I am here!</div>
                <button @click='c.Toggle()'>Toggle me Silly</button>
            </div>
            <components:Header></components:Header>
            <vg-comp expr="c.Body"></vg-comp>
            <components:Footer></components:Footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script type="application/x-go">

import "github.com/vugu/vgrouter"
import "log"

type Root struct {
    vgrouter.NavigatorRef
    Body vugu.Builder // main body content
    AutoReload bool // set to true during dev
    Show bool `vugu:"data"`
}

func (c *Root) Init(ctx vugu.InitCtx) {
    log.Println(c.AutoReload)
    log.Println(c.Show)
 }

func (c *Root) Toggle() { 
    c.Show = !c.Show
    log.Println(c.Show)
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove things that are related to `vgrouter` it works.

```golang
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="root">
            <div>
                <div vg-if='c.Show'>I am here!</div>
                <button @click='c.Toggle()'>Toggle me Silly</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script type="application/x-go">

import "log"

type Root struct {
    Show bool `vugu: "data"`
}


func (c *Root) Toggle() { 
    c.Show = !c.Show
    log.Println(c.Show)
}

</script>
```

Check it:
https://play.vugu.org/?p=H4sIAAAAAAAC_2yQwU7DMBBE7_sVU1_aIrW5I8fiyg1RPqCu4zoWTjZyN4Wq4t9RYhVExW12vG-0Y1213jaGAEAfuLkUOY9NPCM2tcrMon7929tf54c4h0081ku33bX8sTTPsB1an_1CV_9Dh1GEezy5FN37BL5xCMmv1ktTFDqPXUzpoquye3dLyaW7uchSSVetdMkQ6ZPLcRDIZfC1ssOQorMSua8-N4GVIYrdwFmgEgdFNO3hlVlwkjw6wXXOnarhwJywP49hfIRqrFi1py8iOo69w8rhYeLWuLXBFTNbPgY1FkXNZuKwfcmxl9Svir2esnRV7jXfAQAA__8KPfQspwEAAA%3D%3D

So pay attention to how you add `vgrouter`

Comment: This indeed works in the playground and in a new project from scratch. but for some reason it won't work in my project. Feel free to check it out: https://github.com/VanCoppenolleWout/VuguMovies

Comment: @WoutVC Thanks for the link to github! I going to check it a bit later